# How to close firefox when the system feels so bad that the cursor barely moves?

Tags: debian, memory, firefox, lag, defragment

I have a habit of having lots of tabs in my browser. Now I am using Debian and Firefox after many years of being Windows user.
This habit is not a problem on Windows because mouse/cursor is totally alive and it is almost always possible to kill some application from panel and taskmgr is always able to kill processes except of very rare conditions.
And to tell the truth, Windows never tries to defragment RAM so badly that this is more rapid to reboot the system and open everything again than to wait the end of the defragmentation.
Sometimes Firefox is fully falling when I open too many tabs, or few tabs are falling, sometimes the system hangs by 1-2 minutes and gets alive, signalling me to close some tabs right now, but most of the times when I observe an HDD indicator becomes almost 100% time active, I just press reboot. But I consider hard reset as kind of disrespect to my machine, doing this regularly means that something is misconfigured.

How to solve that problem?

1. Is it possible to configurate Firefox (or Linux kernell, I don't know how it works) that I want to fall fast even when having half of free RAM in theory, instead of waiting for a long and uncertain time and melting my SSD for no good reason?
2. I have an experience from my first Linux distro (Ubuntu 9.10) of using Ctrl-Shift-F1 and entering into kernel console where no heavy bells and whistles will delay me from executing `killall firefox` command - how to enter this console in modern Debian?
3. Maybe something else can help me? I've heard about magic keys with SysRq - can this feature be programmed to kill Firefox? I know Firefox has Ctrl-Shift-Q or something similar but I never appreciate using so simple combination for doing something as destructive as closing browser
   (I use browsers in private mode only, so closing the browser has some significant amount of destruction if being pressed accidentally; also I love experimenting with no-qwerty layouts, so from UI's PoV I am a monkey endlessly spamming some random key combinations).

Killing Firefox with hard to reach button really seems like a best decision possible in my situation and seems that second-best option is to get rid of swap except of when compiling some heavy things.
Currently my primary laptop has 4GB of RAM and 1GB of swap and I do not believe that increasing the RAM (therefore decreasing battery life) allows me to get rid of this problem.